# Glide library stopped in AsyncTask.doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment, android-glide

I have a Image URL that I retrieved from database and I want to show it inside image view. I use the Glide library for this purpose but I have an `Exception` while `doInBackground` is running.

```
public class Main extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    private static String url = "http://timit.ir/select/select_pro";
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "Pro_ID";
    public static final String TAG_PIMAGE = "Url";
    public static final String TAG_PNAME = "Pro_Name";
    public static final String TAG_PRICE = "Price";
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String TAG_OLDPRICE = "oldPrice";
    public static final String TAG_COMPANYNAME = "companyName";
    public List<Card> cardList;

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_main, container, false);

        l1 = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal2);

        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        return rootView;
    }

    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Card>> {
        @Override protected List<Card> doInBackground(String... args) {

            cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        Card card = new Card(getActivity());

                        Log.d("url:", c.getString(TAG_PIMAGE));
                        Glide.with(Main.this).load(c.getString(TAG_PIMAGE)).into(card.productThumbnailImage);

                        card.productId = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        card.productName.setText(c.getString(TAG_PNAME));
                        card.price.setText(c.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        card.description.setText(c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));
                        card.companyName.setText(c.getString(TAG_COMPANYNAME));
                        card.oldPrice.setText(c.getString(TAG_OLDPRICE));

                        cardList.add(card);
                    }
                    return cardList;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return cardList;
        }

        @Override protected void onPostExecute(List<Card> lcard) {
            super.onPostExecute(lcard);
            if (lcard.size() != 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lcard.size(); i++) {
                    l1.addView(lcard.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My log:

> 07-02 11:38:59.506: D/url:(4967): http://timit.ir/product_pic
>       /iphone6plusthumnail.png

Comment: Please Help me . There is no any one can help me for this problem ???

Comment: You might have more luck if you posted the exception you refer to

Comment: Ughh, include the error from your logcat!  You are not going to get an answer without showing what the error is.

Comment: Also it helps a lot if people can read your code and see some structure. It's hard to believe that you really have this messy code in your app. If you really do you should look into "Auto formatting code in <your IDE>". I fixed it for you now.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `.into(ImageView)` on a background thread.
I'm pretty sure there's something like this in your log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: net.twisterrob.app, PID: 11027
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    ...
Caused by:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must call this method on the main thread
    ...
```

To fix it store the PIMAGE string in `Card` and then in `onPostExecute`:

```
Card card = lcard.get(i);
Glide.with(Main.this).load(card.imageUrl).into(card.productThumbnailImage);
```